# Template for directive 'zfAsButton' must have exactly one root element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, zurb-foundation

I have a foundation app in meteor with angularjs. I used the zf-as-button directive, but it says error

```
Template for directive 'zfAsButton' must have exactly one root element
```

I came to find out that the issue is resolvable by enclosing the directive template into a div or span OR by removing the replace: true, but I cannot do this for the foundation package as it is included in gitignore and won't work in other cases.
Has anyone else had this issue? Any help would be appreciated

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used foundation app but, according to the project source code, that problem should not be happening using foundation's templates.

You can see that `zfAsButton` directive is using `components/actionsheet/actionsheet-button.htm` template (https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/blob/master/dist/js/foundation-apps.js#L1208)

If you look at the template in
https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/blob/master/dist/js/foundation-apps-templates.js#L18 you'll see that the template has one root element, as expected when a directive has `replace:true` in its definition.

Review which template is the one being loaded, as it doesn't look like the one I referenced before.

Comment: Ahh well I was using meteor and found out meteor doesnot include the foundation-app-templates.js. 
The error reporting system sucks in this case. Thank you anyways